# UICollectionView resize reload itself

Tags: ios, resize, uicollectionview, reload

I'm calling a method that change origin and size of a `UICollectionView` but everytime I do it, the `UICollectionView` is fully reloaded (everytime I do resize or change origin the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method is called).

This makes flicker the view everytimes I call this method.

Is there any way to resize without calling `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 0):

when you change bounds

```
[collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
```